# how to do pagination when tableview at top

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to do pagination when user scroll `tableView` to top, for that i have used this `UIScrollView` method. but it will call api multiple time

Comment: top means when your tableview displayed last cell ?

Comment: no, first time i will get 10 records, when i scroll to top for displaying old comments.

Comment: @KKRocks, can you suggest me to avoid repeat data insertion in array.

Comment: repeat means do you have called same api for multiple times ?

Comment: yes it will call multiple times when i scroll tableview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ry this

**When your server gives number of count for data**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) { // indexpath.row == 0 means top cell in tableViewCell
        if (arrNews.count  < totalPageCount  ) { //totalPageCount means total number of data exist in server which is needs in server resopnse
            [self getDataFromServer];
        }
    }
}
```

**When your server not gives number of count for data**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) { // indexpath.row == 0 means top cell in tableViewCell
        if (isMoreData) { //isMoreData is bolean you need to disable while not data found from server
            [self getDataFromServer];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is totalpagecount?

Comment: i have explained that its count of server data that represents how money data remain in server .

Comment: from server response, i am getting bunch of 10 record when i call api, i am not getting how many remains data are there? and every time when tableview at top i again call api to get new records like whatsapp.

Comment: you needs that number count because how to we know that server have not more data exist .

Comment: i pass one param page_id , it will increase when i got response and when i call api again it will call with increase page_id so if data is not available than it will not return.

Comment: when i get comments response, i want to scroll tableview to bottom & for that i will use this [self.tblVWComments setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)];[self.tblVWComments reloadData]; but it will not scroll to bottom of tableview.

Comment: [self.tblVWComments reloadData] call before [self.tblVWComments setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)];

Comment: if i write reload method above this [self.tblVWComments setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)]; first time 10 data is loaded when new data added and this code call again than no comments are displayed.

Comment: try to change your line my code :     [self. tblVWComments scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.messages.count-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

Comment: actually i also write this line [self.tblVWComments setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)]; above .

Comment: read comment about your scroll at bottom line : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770189/3901620

Comment: thanks, your second answer with bool management worked for me.

Comment: still i am facing problem in scrolling tablview to bottom

Comment: i am facing problem with this method, i think this method will not use for pagination. For Example when API call 1st time, i got 10 records, so bool variable os true that more data is available. this method calls everytime when each cell i s gone out of tableview bound so api continueously calling so there's repeating data issue.

Comment: so i already suggested you that you need to count from server.

Comment: as i told you that i didn't get number of total comments count, i just pass page_id and based on that i receive next comments.

Comment: yes but you ask to your back end developer for this count.

Comment: i know the total number of comments, can i use your 1st answer with static number of comments?

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with contentOffset in `scrollViewDidScroll`

If content offset y position is <=20 and you don't reach the last item call your load more service (pagination records)

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 20 && !reachedEndOfItems) {
        currentOffset = self.wallProfileTableView.contentOffset;
        [self loadMoreMessage];
    }
}
```

It will be similar as we load the chats on scrolling down

Comment: what's reachedEndOfItems?

Comment: its a flag when you are loaded all items like if you call 10 items per page and in at 1 call you receive not more than 10 records it means you have all data no need more paging